# Avoid false positives of latency & CPU spikes when autoscaling is happening

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, autoscaling, aws-auto-scaling

How to know in cloudwatch if autoscaling of EC2 hosts are happening or not? This is to prevent separate alarms going off when there is CPU & latency increase due to traffic increase but autoscaling has already started and will take care of it. In these separate monitors, I want to also include to not alert when autoscaling is happening.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-scaling-cooldowns.html

Comment: Thanks, sorry I was not clear. The autoscaling part is fine. But the issue was that separate CPU and latency monitors are going off due to traffic increase and this is already taken care by autoscaling. I want to exclude the cases where autoscaling is happening in these separate monitors. I have updated the question.